# ng-style with interpolated value not rendering the background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to change a background image of a div using angular ng-style.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="cover-image" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url({{data.image}})'}"></div>
```

However when I run the project the image is not shown instead the url of the image has changed to 'localhost:'

Inspect element shows this,

```
<div class="cover-image" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(<some image url>)'}" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:<port>/);"></div>
```

CSS

```
.cover-image
{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Why is this? How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Following will work too: \'{{data.image}}\'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe `ng-style` will not work when the object expression's key value contains interpolation and when they are bound asynchronously. Instead you may have to bind the style object itself.

Example:-

```
  $scope.data.style = {'background-image' : 'url(/path/to/image)'}
```

and

```
  <div class="cover-image" ng-style="data.style"></div>
```

Interestingly the following works too:

```
<div class="cover-image" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(' + data.image + ')'}">
```

This could be because [ngstyle directive sets watch/watchcollection](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngStyle.js#L49) on the attribute. This is causing the issue when the value of the bound ng-style object's key/value has interpolation and that value is bound dynamically, because ngstyle directive will have set the watch on `attr.ngStyle` which is `{'background-image' : 'url()'}` because of the interpolation having kicked in prior to ngstyle directive. Hence the watch will not execute for the second time to set the style (even though ng-style directive's value will show the interpolation properly on the view), and the initially set style of `element.css({'background-image' : 'url()'})` will render the style with the url as that of the current domain (Which browser does).

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.data.image = 'http://placehold.it/50x50';
    $scope.data.style = {
      'background-image': 'url(http://placehold.it/50x50)'
    }

  }, 1000)

});
```

```css
.cover-image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Will not display
  <div class="cover-image" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url({{data.image}})'}"></div>
  Will display with Object binding
  <div class="cover-image" ng-style="data.style"></div>
  Will display with string concat
  <div class="cover-image" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'url(' + data.image + ')'}"></div>



</div>
```

Comment: This works but I get a warning in the console 
**Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8100/"**

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is something to do with the ionic framework i'm using but the code I posted in the question works fine in another page. I just can't figure out why