# Angular dynamic background image in div

Tags: css, angular, styles

Trying to load image dynamically from server in div but unable to do so:

```
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('https://www.abcd.com/+ post.image)"></div>
```

I have already tried snippets but they don't work from this post [Angular dynamic background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575368/angular-dynamic-background-images)

Comment: If your adding from server, why are u parsing an url, it should go from assets folder on THE server or sum..

Comment: Look at this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608932/ng-style-with-interpolated-value-not-rendering-the-background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want use dynamically. Dont use this syntactic

```
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('https://www.abcd.com/+ post.image)"></div>
```

try do this

```
<div class="thumb" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + post.imageURL + ')'}" > <div>
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: this worked for me thanks .                                                                                                                        <div class="thumb" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' +'https://www.abcd.com/'+ post.imageURL + ')'}" > <div>